# PHP - How to replace text implement to code

Tags: php

How to replace 2 or more text.

here I have code:

```
$new_name = $p['man_name2'];
    $subcat = '';

    if (preg_match('/([^\/]+)$/', $p['category_name'], $m))
    {
        $subcat = $m[1];
        $new_name .= " $subcat";
    }
    {
        $new_name .= ' ' . $prod['custom_name']['value'];
    }
```

To replace text from attribute: `custom name`.  I try in this way:

```
{
    $new_name .= ' ' . $prod['custom_name']['value'];
    $new_name = str_replace('eu de toilet', 'perfume', $new_name);
}
```

But no work.

And also how to replace more than 1 word?

**example:**

In this code I want replace:

- eu de toilet   to perfume
- eu de cologne to perfume

Comment: str_replace can get arrays for replacing multiple phrases (watch manual for more). I can't understand logic of the first part of the code. Pls show input data before replace.  str_replace('eu de toilet', 'perfume', 'some eu de toilet and some'); -> "some perfume and some" This one works fine.

Comment: Vlad, can you please put in answear full code what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Use one of these variants for multiple phrases replace:

```
$text = 'some text eu de toilet and some text eu de cologne and other one text eu de toilet';
$replaced = str_replace(['eu de toilet', 'eu de cologne'], ['perfume', 'perfume'], $text) . PHP_EOL;
// OR
$replaced = str_replace(['eu de toilet', 'eu de cologne'], 'perfume', $text);
//Result: some text perfume and some text perfume and other one text and perfume
```